# Looking for help defining a certain/index variable

Tags: php

I am stuck at arranging this code that I got online.
What I am trying to do is get the value of `textfield="search_box"`
and when the button has been pressed, search the database and display the output from the table rows.

```
require 'db/connect.php'; //collect

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_studreg WHERE id ='{$search_it}'";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {  
    $search_it = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You're trying to interpolate `$search_it` before you define it. It doesn't work that way. Put `$sql = ...` *after* `$search_it = ...`...

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the `$sql` variable with the content of `$search_it` before `$search_it` is defined.
Try to set the `$sql` variable after the `mysql_real_escape_string` command.

In a side note, you are using the obsolete `mysql` extensions. Take a look into the `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions and search for prepared statements and bind variables.